# What i need to activate in PHP? to accept [

Tags: php, parsing, syntax-error

I am programming an app locally, but when I migrate to server I get a parse error using this line:

```
if(!is_array($data[array_keys($data)[0]]))
```

Returns:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' in
>   /home/file.php

If I rewrite the line like this:

```
$var1 = array_keys($data);
if(!is_array($data[$varX[0]]))
```

It works.

What do I need to activate on server, to get it working in the first example without error?

Thanks.

Comment: If your second example works without a hitch, and is more readable.. Then the reasoning of the previous error shouldn't be a problem.. because your code now works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be running PHP version 5.4 to use array dereferencing like that. I suspect on your server you have a lower version of PHP than on your local system.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Under 'New features':

> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called "array dereferencing" which only became available in PHP 5.4. So if your version of PHP is earlier than that like yours is, it won't work.